# Cursor exhausted when code using mongocxx is refactored into two functions instead of one

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++17, mongo-cxx-driver

The following `for_each` method successfully connects through to the database, and the cursor allows it to loop through all the documents in the collection.

My aim is to refactor the **"connecting to database and get collection"** part of this method. So we also have a refactoring `get_collection` method implementing the first 3 lines in the try block.

```
void MyClass::for_each(const std::string &collectionName, std::function<void(nlohmann::json &)> func)
{
  try{
    mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri(uri_string)};
    mongocxx::database testing_db = client.database("db_name");
    mongocxx::collection coll = testing_db.collection(collectionName);
    //auto coll = get_collection("db_name", "Users");
    mongocxx::cursor cursor_users_all = coll.find({});
    for (auto&& doc : cursor_users_all) {
      nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(bsoncxx::to_json(doc)) ;
      func(j);
    }
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "An error occurred: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
}

mongocxx::collection MyClass::get_collection(const std::string &db_name, const std::string &collectionName)
{
  mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri(uri_string)};
  mongocxx::database testing_db = client.database(db_name);
  mongocxx::collection coll = testing_db.collection(collectionName);
  return coll;
}
```

When using the commented line instead of the 3 preceding lines:
The catch block prints: `An error occurred: Another cursor derived from this client is in exhaust.: generic server error`. The exception happens at the for loop line.

Why is it that we cannot return a collection object? I have also tried wrapping it in a shared pointer with std::move. Is there no way to refactor this code?

Comment: I'd imagine that as `client` and `testing_db` have been destroyed `coll` is no longer valid